# python binary executable fails to execute on OS x: importerror no module named PyQt4

Tags: python, macos, pyqt4, pyinstaller

I created a binary executable on Mac for a python script using `pyinstaller` and the following command:

> pyinstaller --onefile --windowed chatEdit.py

also tried this:

> pyinstaller --windowed chatEdit.py

In each case the executable fails to run.

A terminal screen opens up and displays the following message:

```
Failed to execute script chatEdit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chatEdit.py", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
logout
```

Please help!

My .spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['chatEdit.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/Shubhi/Documents/vin'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='chatEdit',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='chatEdit')
app = BUNDLE(coll,
             name='chatEdit.app',
             icon=None,
             bundle_identifier=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed PyQt in .spec file

I hope my app.spec will help you. Pay attention to **'PyQt4.QtCore', 'PyQt4.QtGui'** in *hiddenimports*

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['app.py'],
             pathex=['d:\\4com\\consultant\\consultant'],
             hiddenimports=['grab.transport.curl', 'pycurl', 'weblib.user_agent', 'grab.response','openpyxl',
             'openpyxl.styles', 'cookielib','_LWPCookieJar','_MozillaCookieJar','PyQt4.QtCore', 'PyQt4.QtGui',
             'gui'],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='documents.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
```

Comment: My .spec has nothing listed in hiddenimports(updated the qn with spec file). Should I directly edit the spec file?

Comment: Yes. You should add PyQt imports at least. As in my file. It is from successfully compiled project. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Edited it. How do I run the binary using this new spec?

Comment: You need to run `pyinstaller [yourscriptname].spec` to recompile according to new parameters you provide.

Comment: File "<string>", line 10
    hiddenimports=[‘PyQt4.QtCore’, ‘PyQt4.QtGui’],
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Chat conversation end

Comment: It is good that you post your .spec file, but I can't see there PyQt4 in hiddenimports, can you show me edited file with PyQt4 there to help you find SyntaxError?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is important, but let's try: first you do `pyi-makespec chatEdit.py --onefile --windowed` and then edit .spec file it generated, then `pyinstaller chatEdit.spec`. At least that helped me one day.